# In Windows 8.1 what is Windows 8.1 Secondary Plex?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

We have a Windows 8.1 Machine and we just setup and added a mirror RAID to it.  Now when it boots up it asks if I want to boot into Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.1 Secondary Plex.

Does the secondary plex mean boot from the mirrored drive instead of the primary drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you created the mirror within Windows itself (a software RAID), and that's how you ended up with that option.

Windows can't have a boot entry that points to more than one volume, so they provide that additional boot option so that you can boot from the secondary drive in the Mirror, in the event of failure of the primary drive.